# "isDuped" predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a predicate in prolog called `isDuped( Y )` that only succeeds if `Y` is a list of even length and each element in the list appears twice in a row (i.e. `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]`).
What I currently have is:

```
isDuped( Y ) :-
    Y == [].
isDuped( Y ) :-
    [ A, B | C ] = Y,
    A == B,
    isDuped( C ).
```

However, one of my professor's unit tests is supposed to return true, but as I have it written it returns false.  `isDuped([1,_])` is supposed to return true, but I have no idea what I need to change.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
isDuped( [] ).
isDuped([A, A | C] ) :-
    isDuped( C ).
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, comparison `A == B` checks if the terms `A` and `B` are identical. An uninstantiated variable and a number are not identical terms.

What your professor seems to want (not clear from the problem formulation you gave, but clear from the test) is unification `=`: just change `A == B` to `A = B`.